# using multiple tap gestures with UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I am creating a `UILabel` that needs to have two gestures, a single tap and a double tap.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(labelView)
    labelView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        quoteLabelView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
    view.leadingAnchor),
        quoteLabelView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
    view.trailingAnchor),
        quoteLabelView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
    view.topAnchor),
}

var labelView: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    let singleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSingleTap))
    let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTap))
    singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    label.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGesture)
    label.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)
    return label
}()

}
```

I read apples documentation which provides info on preferring one gesture over another but I don't know how to apply this to the label. 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/touches_presses_and_gestures/coordinating_multiple_gesture_recognizers/preferring_one_gesture_over_another

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
                       shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    // Don't recognize a single tap until a double-tap fails.
    if gestureRecognizer == self.tapGesture &&
        otherGestureRecognizer == self.doubleTapGesture {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add your gesture recognizers inside your label declaration, you're probably better off using separate funcs for single- and double- taps:

```
class TestViewController: UIViewController {

    lazy var labelView: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let singleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didSingleTap(_:)))
        singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        label.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGesture)

        let doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didDoubleTap(_:)))
        doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        label.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)

        singleTapGesture.require(toFail: doubleTapGesture)

        return label
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // add the labelView        
        view.addSubview(labelView)

        // set a couple properties
        labelView.text = "Tap or Double-Tap Me"
        labelView.textAlignment = .center
        labelView.backgroundColor = .yellow

        // constrain it to the view
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            labelView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 200),
            labelView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            labelView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
        ])

    }

    @objc func didSingleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        print("Did Single Tap")
    }

    @objc func didDoubleTap(_ gesture: UITapGestureRecognizer) -> Void {
        print("Did Double Tap")
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the link you shared says, you need to set the delegate for the gestures recognizers:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {

var singleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSingleTap))
var doubleTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTap)) 

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.addSubview(labelView)
    setupGestures()
    labelView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
        quoteLabelView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
    view.leadingAnchor),
        quoteLabelView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
    view.trailingAnchor),
        quoteLabelView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: 
    view.topAnchor),
}

func setupGestures() {
    singleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    singleTapGesture.delegate = self
    doubleTapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    doubleTapGesture.delegate = self
    labelView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTapGesture)
    labelView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGesture)
}

var labelView: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    return label
}()

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer,
                   shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
    // Don't recognize a single tap until a double-tap fails.
    if gestureRecognizer == self.tapGesture &&
        otherGestureRecognizer == self.doubleTapGesture {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
}
```

And then the method you posted.

Also, you need be able to access the gesture, so remove them from the label.